# How to get children id when I click the parent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

```
<div class="big" onclick="dataadd()">
   <div id="a">child1</div>
   <div id="b">child2</div>
</div>
```

When I click the div with `class="big"` tag, I wanna get the children's id or text.
I tried all several methods, but I can't handle it. Anyone know how to do it? Javascript or Jquery doesn't matter.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

You can pass your clicked element by `dataadd(this)`;

You may wonder how `this` comes inside the method. adding `this` keyword like above will refer to the current element.

Then using that element, you can find children and with `each` you can grab other details by loop through the children.

```js
function dataadd(ele){
 var children = $(ele).find('div');
    children.each(function(idx, element){
      console.log($(element).attr('id'));
 
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="big" onclick="dataadd(this)">
   <div id="a">child1</div>
   <div id="b">child2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `children()` to selecting childs of element and use `map()` to mapping elements to id attribute.

```js
$(".big").click(function(){
  var ids = $(this).children().map(function(){
    return this.id;
  }).toArray();
  console.log(ids);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="big">
   <div id="a">child1</div>
   <div id="b">child2</div>
</div>
```

Also you can use simpler code as shown in bottom

```
$(".big").click(function(){
  console.log(
    $('> *', this).map((i, val) => val.id).toArray()
  );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For a more modern way with ES6:

```
document.querySelector(".big").addEventListener('click', function(e){
    [...e.target.children].forEach(function(child){
        const { id, innerText } = child;
        console.log(id, innerText);
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the context using `this` and use `querySelectorAll` to get the `div` and then its `id`

```js
function dataadd(elem) {
  elem.querySelectorAll('div').forEach(function(item) {
    console.log(item.id)
  })
}
```

```html
<div class="big" onclick="dataadd(this)">
  <div id="a">child1</div>
  <div id="b">child2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function dataadd(){
   $(this).children().each(function(){
      console.log($(this).attr('id'));
   })
}
```

This code will print ids of `big` div.

Comment: This won't work as `this` will be the `window` in your example, not the element which was clicked.